# chaoshunter open-source alternative

Tags: cluster, grid

Does anyone know of an open-source alternative to [Chaos Hunter](http://www.chaoshunter.com/)?

Mainly one that could use the full power of a grid-cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, most open source projects that have capabilities comparable to commercial market predication software quickly become closed source. I do remember though seeing a tutorial on using Neuroph for this sort of thing. You can find it [here](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/StockMarketPredictionTutorial.html). The page includes download links for everything you'll need.